# AdRequest Class conflict in GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar and google-play-services.jar

Tags: android, admob, ads, google-play-services

I am including `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar` and `google-play-services.jar` into my Android project.

The issue I am facing is both jar files contains `AdRequest.class`.I am trying to access AdRequest class present in GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar but I think classloader is confused since both jar files contains class with same name and same package name.Is there any workaround to overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options:

1. Ditch Admob-6.4.1 and use the new Admob classes (they are in the com.google.android.gms.ads package now though GPS also contains the old classes) from Google play Services. This is the recommended approach going forwards.
2. If you really need to use Admob-6.4.1 alongside GPS (you should be asking why) then you will have to manually edit the Admob classes out of the GPS library.

Definitely go with option 1 if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks for the input.Definitely I would go with option 1.The problem is I am developing Mediation adapter and I haven't got mediation adapter helper project for GPS.I have it for Admob 6.4.1.

Comment: If you are developing a CustomEvent (mediation adapater) then it is not much different between Admob-6.4.1 and the classes in GPS (other than the new package).